# 'sharedLib' in solr.xml not affecting after upgrading from solr 4.7 to solr 5.5.5

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am trying to upgrade solr 4.7 to solr 5.5.5.
In solr 4.7 solr.xml contained `<str name="sharedLib">common</str>` so configuration files such as `solrconfig.xml` loaded from the path '$SOLR_HOME/solr/common/conf' instead loading this file from each core.

Now, after upgrading to solr 5.5.5, I put the same 'sharedLib' but after starting solr I see errors in the UI for each core:

> **mycore_1**: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core mycore_1: Error loading solr config from ($SOLR_HOME)/solr/mycore_1/conf/solrconfig.xml
>   **mycore_2**: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core mycore_2: Error loading solr config from ($SOLR_HOME)/solr/mycore_2/conf/solrconfig.xml
>   **remote_shared_instance**: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core remote_shared_instance: Error loading solr config from ($SOLR_HOME)/solr/remote_shared_instance/conf/solrconfig.xml

Seems that it tried to  search for the configuration files in the core's folders instead in the shared folder.

solr.xml placed in the right folder ($SOLR_HOME) because when deleting this file I get the message: 'olr home directory $SOLR_HOME/solr must contain a solr.xml file!' when starting solr.

I start solr from $SOLR_HOME which is different from the solr installation folder.

This is how the 'solr' section in solr.xml file looks:

```
<solr>

  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

  <str name="sharedLib">common</str>

</solr>
```

I also tried using `configsets` - I created a new folder under $SOLR_HOME 'solr/solr/configsets/common/conf' with cond files but how can I tell solr to refer to this folder? NOTE that the original 'configsets' folder is under solr installation folder 'solr-5.5.5/server/solr/configsets' and not under $SOLR_HOME.

Have I missed something?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Have you looked at [configsets instead](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-sets.html#config-sets)? I thought the sharedLib-directory was meant for jars etc

Comment: Yes, I am just looking on it. I created a new folder under $SOLR_HOME 'solr/solr/configsets/common/conf' with cond files but how can I tell solr to refer to this folder?  NOTE that the original 'configsets' folder is under solr installation folder 'solr-5.5.5/server/solr/configsets' and not under $SOLR_HOME

Comment: `The default base directory is $SOLR_HOME/configsets, and it can be configured in solr.xml.`. You'll have to recreate the core with the `configSet` property.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to recreate the core - it seems that it fails (Bad request). Can you please tell me how can I define this new folder in the `solr.xml` (it looks easy to find but I couldn't find how). Thanks!

Comment: `<solr><str name="configSetBaseDir">....`